# Remote PostgreSQL connection from external client on Windows

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, system

i am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL DB which is hosted on Windows 10 machine.

I have changed the following settings on ini file:

- listen_addresses = '*' is set in postgresql.conf
- host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 is set pg_hba.conf

I have enabled the 5432 port for TCP/IP connections and I have checked that it is listening.

Results:

- **IT WORKS** when I try to connect to the DB from a machine that is under the same network as the machine hosting the server using the private IP for connection
- **IT DOES NOT WORK** when I try to connect to the DB from a machine outside the network of the machine hosting the server, using the public IP for connection

I have seen several topics about it, but the only suggestions are to modify init file and add a rule to open TCP/IP on 5432 port.

Could you please help?
thanks!

Comment: It has to do with [routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_routing) i doubt this is the place to explain for such a thing, because if you are doing this wrong, EVERYONE has access to you database.

Comment: Two things  1) The external router has a firewall blocking port 5432 and/or 2) The external router is not set up to port forward from the public IP to the private IP. In either/both case(s) per @Luuk this is something you need to think seriously about and consult with whoever maintains the external router.

Comment: Hi guys and thanks for your help, and thanks for security issues. So what would be the best way to configure a postgre DB that could be accessed from a machine that is not under the same LAN taking into account the best security possible? 

Thanks again!